# Matlab xUnit Framework test suite setup

Tags: unit-testing, matlab, xunit

How to initialize variables once per test suite, such that they are visible in each test? It can be for example loading some files, which each test is needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to Matlab xUnit documentation: You could either 1) inherit from TestCase or 2) use subfunctions. Example using subfunctions is shown below. You can only pass one variable, so you have to load them in a struct as shown below. You can put additional subfunctions at end, but make sure you start or end their names with 'setup', 'test', or 'teardown'

```
function test_suite = testjkcmInputParser    
    initTestSuite;

    function d = setup
    d.file='garbagelog.log';
    d.fid = fopen(d.file, 'w');
    d.o = jkcmInputParser(d.fid);

    function teardown(d)
    delete(d.o);
    fclose(d.fid);
    delete(d.file);

    function testConstructorNoInput(d)
    %constructor without fid
    delete(d.o);
    d.o = jkcmInputParser();    
    assertEqual(isa(d.o,'jkcmInputParser'), true, 'not a jkcmInputParser');
    assertEqual(isa(d.o,'inputParser'), true, 'not an inputParser');

    function testConstructorWithInput(d)
    %constructor with fid    
    assertEqual(isa(d.o,'jkcmInputParser'), true, 'not a jkcmInputParser');
    assertEqual(isa(d.o,'inputParser'), true, 'not an inputParser');
    initializejkcmParser(d.o);      
    s = d.o.printHelp();    
    assertEqual(s, correctPrintHelp(), 'output of printHelp does not match expected.');

    function outP = initializejkcmParser(o)
    %setup jkcmInputParser
    o.addRequired('val1_noComment', @isnumeric);
    o.addRequired('val2', @isnumeric, 'comment');    
    o.addOptional('val3_noComment',3, @isnumeric);
    o.addOptional('val4',15, @isnumeric, 'another great comment!');    
    o.addParamValue('val5_noComment', 45, @isnumeric);
    o.addParamValue('val6', 45, @isnumeric, 'This is the greatest comment');
    outP = o;

    function outP = correctPrintHelp()
    outP = sprintf(...  
       ['val1_noComment: Req : \n',...
        'val2: Req : comment\n',...
        'val3_noComment: Opt : \n',...
        'val4: Opt : another great comment!\n',...
        'val5_noComment: Param : \n',...
        'val6: Param : This is the greatest comment\n']);
```

Comment: setup function is called before each test. I need a way to load before ALL tests once and to clean after ALL tests.

Comment: Would global variables work? If not then I imagine you will have to use the class framework and inherit from testSuite and make some changes.

Comment: Maybe a `persistent` variable would be better than a `global`.

Answer (score 1):

In R2013a MATLAB includes a fully featured test framework. One of the features it includes is the ability to define setup/teardown code for an entire class.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html